# using strpos in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, database, string, function

I'm not sure if this is the correct function in using mysql but I was wondering if someone can help me with this problem I'm having

Ex:

I have mysql with these values

```
id     name
1      house_home
2      movie_film
3      restaurant_food
```

So if I'm trying to find `movie`, it should get the value movie_film.

Is strpos function the right function for this case? Or is there another way?

```
$string = 'movie';
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM values WHERE name = ?";
$query->execute(array($string));
while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    echo $row['name']; //this should output movie_film
}
```

Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: `LIKE` may be what you are looking for?

Comment: You will use "like"query in mysql. you will get "movie_film"

Comment: Why do you have `house_home` in one column instead of having `house` in one and `home` in another? String manipulation is slow.

Answer (score 21):

Using strpos you will get the position of that string and then trim the length you want

Use `LOCATE('substring', 'mainstring')` function

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate

Comment: To trim, the SQL `TRIM()` function will not do the job as it only trims specified characters: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim Instead what you need is `SUBSTRING()`: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `LIKE` 'operator' in SQL.

`SELECT * FROM values WHERE name LIKE '%?%'`

Answer (score 1):

Please try `LIKE operator` for it

```
SELECT * from values where name LIKE '%?%';
```